# executing code after download starts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add an animated loader image, which would appear after the user triggers downloading of an attachment, and disappear after the download actually starts - when the browser starts downloading the file (or displays the download confirmation dialog). The reason for it is that the attachments are quite complex documents generated on the server side, which takes some time and an animated loader would reassure the user that the page is working (and disable the download button until the download starts).

The attachment has properly set Http headers.

Here is what it looks like now:

```
var link = $("#download-link");
link.click(function () {
  link.displayLoader();
  $(document).load(link.attr("href"), function () {
    link.hideLoader();
  });
  return false;
});
```

The main problem is that the `load` method obviously doesn't do what I would like to achieve. Is there a way to capture the actual start of downloading, triggered by `window.location` change?

Answer (score 1):

You can do is.

Disable the whole screen until the Download is ready ( the server side processing).

And the user clicks a button download and the user directly downloads the file.

Approaches followed by most of the downloading website.
eg. Mediafire.com

PS: Disable the whole screen mean a System type dialog. disabling other options.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Why don't you show the loader image first?</s>

If I understand correctly now, the problem is that you want the loader image to disappear once the file begins to download, and at present it disappears once the file has finished downloading?

I don't think there's an easy way to do it with jQuery, but if you drop down to using the normal JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest` object directly, you will get several callbacks at various stages of downloading that you can access through the `readyState` property.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The loader image is shown by the `displayLoader()` method, which I didn't include in the question for the sake of simplicity but I thought its name was self explanatory.

Comment: he does want to show the loader first, which he is doing. i think the question is how can he HIDE the loader when the "download actually starts" (whatever that means)

Comment: It means - when the browser starts downloading the file.

Comment: Right, got it.  "Doesn't do what I would like" is a bit ambiguous.  Updating answer now.

Comment: I'm sorry for the ambiguity, English is not my first language.